# QEMU and CentOS 8: Where is /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 and the qemu-system-x86 package?

Tags: centos, kvm, qemu, libvirt

I am trying to create and run a virtual machine on a headless server running CentOS 8 (x86-64).

After installing the necessary tools like `libvirt` and `kvm` it seems `qemu` is missing its main executable, the QEMU PC System emulator, `/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64`:

On a CentOS 7 machine (on which I have done this a dozen times) I ran

```
root@centos7> rpm -qf /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64
qemu-system-x86-2.0.0-1.el7.6.x86_64
```

However, there is no such package on CentOS 8:

```
root@centos8> dnf se qemu-system |& tail -1
No matches found.
```

Where is this executable?  Is there no working QEMU system provided for CentOS 8?

```
root@centos8> dnf se qemu | uniq
Last metadata expiration check: 0:30:19 ago on (...)
========================= Name & Summary Matched: qemu =========================
qemu-guest-agent.x86_64 : QEMU guest agent
qemu-kvm-core.x86_64 : qemu-kvm core components
qemu-kvm-block-ssh.x86_64 : QEMU SSH block driver
qemu-kvm-block-curl.x86_64 : QEMU CURL block driver
qemu-kvm-block-iscsi.x86_64 : QEMU iSCSI block driver
qemu-kvm-block-rbd.x86_64 : QEMU Ceph/RBD block driver
qemu-kvm-block-gluster.x86_64 : QEMU Gluster block driver
qemu-kvm.x86_64 : QEMU is a machine emulator and virtualizer
qemu-img.x86_64 : QEMU command line tool for manipulating disk images
qemu-kvm-common.x86_64 : QEMU common files needed by all QEMU targets
libvirt-daemon-driver-qemu.x86_64 : QEMU driver plugin for the libvirtd daemon
ipxe-roms-qemu.noarch : Network boot loader roms supported by QEMU, .rom format
standard-test-roles-inventory-qemu.noarch : Inventory provisioner for using
                                          : plain qemu command
============================ Summary Matched: qemu =============================
libvirt-lock-sanlock.x86_64 : Sanlock lock manager plugin for QEMU driver
```

(two duplicates manually removed in the above output).

PS: It works fine in Arch Linux:

```
root@arch> pacman -Qo /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64
/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 is owned by qemu-headless 5.0.0-5
```

PPS: [Red Hat's docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/8.0_release_notes/index#virtualization) do say that CentOS 8 can use QEMU/KVM.

PPPS (solution): Searching for `/usr/bin/qemu-kvm` as suggested by @StephenKitt :

```
root@centos8> dnf se qemu-kvm
(...)
root@centos8> dnf in qemu-kvm.x86_64 qemu-kvm-core.x86_64 qemu-kvm-common.x86_64 
(... 4x "is already installed.")
Nothing to do.
root@centos8> dnf whatprovides /usr/bin/qemu-kvm
(...)
Error: No Matches found
Exit 1
root@centos8> locate qemu-kvm
(...)
/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm
(...)
root@centos8> rpm -qf /usr/libexec/qemu-kvm
qemu-kvm-core-2.12.0-88.module_el8.1.0+297+df420408.3.x86_64
```

OK, got it. They have also changed the location.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main QEMU executable is now `qemu-kvm`; that’s what is used to start a KVM-enabled VM.

Comment: OK, thanks!  They have also changed the location to `/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm` but I have found the file now. Do you have a reference to the rationale why the emulator doesn't have a platform-specific name anymore?

Comment: Strange there isn't a symbolic links to qemu-kvm in e.g. `/usr/bin/qemu-kvm`. One could even argue that the RPM package should also create a link `/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64` (running CentOS 9 Stream)

Comment: At least on RHEL 8, I see a message saying that I should be using libvirt and not qemu-kvm to manage my images.  Maybe that is why the binary is not linked to a standard location?

/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm -h | head
QEMU emulator version 6.2.0 (qemu-kvm-6.2.0-20.module+el8.7.0+16905+efca5d32.2)
Copyright (c) 2003-2021 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers

WARNING: Direct use of qemu-kvm from the command line is not supported by Red Hat.
WARNING: Use libvirt as the stable management interface.
WARNING: Some command line options listed here may not be available in future releases

Comment: Also `/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm -machine help` lists very few options